# How to check for NaN values in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array called `pos` returned by `outerarc.centroid` function which may have NaN values as well. I want those values to be assigned with 0.

I am using the following logic:

```
var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
pos.forEach(function(d, i) { 
  console.log(d + " " + i);
  if(d==NaN){
    d = 0;
  }
  console.log(d + " " + i);
});
var x = pos[0],
    y = pos[1],
    h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

But it's not working. How else can I check for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, NaN is the only thing that's not equal to anything, not even to itself!

```js
var a = NaN;
console.log("Is NaN equal to NaN? " + (a === a));
console.log("Is NaN different from NaN? " + (a !== a));
```

That being said, you can do:

```
if(d !== d){
    d = 0;
}
```

Assuming that you have an array of primitives, which is the case of `centroid`, **not** an array of objects (in that situation, you have to choose the property using `d.foo`).